# How best to communicate between two ASP.NET Core server apps?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two ASP.NET Core web apps (on different physical servers), and both use EF Core. Although both are "servers", one also collects data from the other (i.e. one of them is also a "client").

ASP.NET Core is different because there is no "MVC" and "WebAPI", it combines both. I'm not sure what new APIs to use.

How should I transfer data from one to the other?

My initial thought is the "client" app has an authenticated and authorized GET action which returns the data. But how? Can it directly return an EF entity, or am I responsible for serialization to/from JSON? Should it return `IActionResult` or something else? Should it be a regular or AJAX request? Is OWIN related to this somehow?

*Is there any smart technique which is now available with ASP.NET Core?* I don't need a solution, just some pointers in the right direction.

Comment: From the perspective of the client, it makes no difference whether the server is "Core" or "Web API" or any other technology.  The resulting external behavior is the same regardless of what framework is being used under the hood.  I imagine you would have actions which return data (likely JSON format, though you can use any format you want) just like you would in previous versions of Web API.

Comment: @David Sure, but Core is the new and shiny, and I have a suspicion that there might be some cool stuff to make all this easy. For example, it allows for returning of all kinds of data from actions, which could not be done before. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, basically.

Comment: In previous versions of Web API, if you wanted to "return an EF entity" then you would just `return` that object from that method.  I don't see how it could have gotten any simpler than that.  In C# when you want to return something from a method, you `return` it.  Regardless of how new it is, the framework is still using C#.  Maybe you can clarify with an example of what you're trying to simplify?

Comment: @David I didn't know you can simply return an entity. I can't find any mention of that on [the asp.net core docs site](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/). Is it automatically serialized to JSON?

Comment: This looks applicable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting  There are a variety of options, depending on how much control you need over the response.  A JSON-formatted response body with a `200 OK` response code is generally the default when returning any object.  But you can have more control over HTTP responses by using specific framework result types and helper methods.  (Such as `Ok()` or `Json()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the framework may have new helper methods/objects/etc. here or there, nothing's really changed regarding HTTP communication between a client and a server.  Indeed, from the perspective of the client, there's no difference in the server regardless of what technology is used under the hood.

> Can it directly return an EF entity

It sure can, just as Web API has in the past.  Something as simple as:

```
public Widget Get(int id)
{
    return _widgetRepository.Get(id);
}
```

(Assuming an implementation of a repository of some sort here, but you get the idea.)

The default HTTP response for this is generally a JSON-formatted response body and a `200 OK` response code.  You can have more control over that with a variety of framework helpers, there's a decent overview and introduction to a couple of them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting).

Regardless of how you return any given result from the server, the client is still getting an HTTP response like any other.  Codes, headers, content, etc.